# Something is wrong with this 3-panes splitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to resize 3 panes inside a container , when resized, they shouldn't exceed the width of container (do not get out of it)..
But in this snippet http://jsfiddle.net/KXsrd/ , when I resize the second one, it successfully decreases the next element or increases depending on the direction. but sometimes it causes the next sibling to drop below the container and although the next sibling decreases its size when I expand one , it keeps 'shaking' ..

Here is the main function:

```
   $(function () {

        $('.col').each(function (e, u) {
            $(u).data({ow: $(u).width()});
        })
        $(".col").resizable(
                {
                    handles: 'e',
                    start: function (e) {

                    },
                    resize: function (e, ui) {

                        var el = ui.element;
                        var parent = el.parent();
                        var next = el.next();
                        var siblings = el.siblings();
                        var siblingsWidth = (function () {
                            var totalWidth = 0;
                            _.each(siblings, function (el) {
                                totalWidth += $(el).width();
                            });
                            return totalWidth;
                        })();
                        var currentSize = ui.size;

                        if (currentSize.width > $(el).data('ow')) {
                            next.css({width: '-=' + (currentSize.width - $(el).data('ow'))});
                        } else {
                            next.css({width: '+=' + (  $(el).data('ow') - currentSize.width )});
                        }
                        if (currentSize.width + siblingsWidth >= $(parent).width()) {

                            $(el).width($(parent).width() - siblingsWidth)

                        }
                        $(el).data({ow: currentSize.width});

                    },
                    stop: function (e, ui) {

                    }
                });
    });
```

Any help would be much appreciated .. 
(PS. I tried many plugins for resizable panes. but they all work on 2 panes only)

Comment: Why do you want to create a splitter? there are many plugins in JQuery, refer to https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.splitter. demo: http://jquery.jcubic.pl/splitter.php

Comment: @jesse yeah I know about this. This is for 2 panes only, if you want more, you need to add nested one into the second which is NOT what I wanted.